# Как получить значение title с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть строка типа:

```
$temp_2='<a href="http://site.ru/catid100603" title="Кухонные столы">Кухонные столы</a>'
```

Как с помощью регулярных выражений получить значение `title` (`"Кухонные столы"`).

Вот что я делал:

```
$patterm = "(title=\"([А-Яа-я]+)\")";
echo preg_replace($patterm , "title=\"\"",$temp_2);
```

Но это у меня не работает.

Хочу из строки `$temp2` получить все значения `title`.

Comment: Это `title=.*?\K[\p{L} ]+(?=.)` - поможет при любых символах или без них впереди.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=title=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))
```

Comment: Окей, тогда напишут так: `<a title=Кухни>Кухни</a>`, тогда ваша регулярка накроется.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/Usi', $text_var, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Comment: Вы видимо плохо читали вопрос. Ваш ответ, не соответствует задаче автора. Ко всему еще и ненужных модификаторов натолкали.